# Execution plan not understanding correctly

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-workbench, execution-plan, query-performance

I am running a query:

```
SELECT * FROM message where fr_user = 1 ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Without the LIMIT there would be 170 rows returned where fr_user = 1;

I am now trying to understand how efficient this query (not trying to improve the query, just to see how efficient it CURRENTLY is) is.

I have ran the query and looked at the execution plan:

- In the execution plan there is a query cost of 43.00... what does this mean/how is it calculated?
- What do the four fields (Read, Eval, Prefix, DataRead) mean?
- Why does the ratio of rows examined to the ratio of rows produced = 100% when there are 170 rows examined and 10 rows produced? I have an index (fr_user, created) so why are all the rows (170) being examined? If I have to examine all the rows it would seem pointless to have an index then?

[image]

Comment: Can mysql read an index partially backwards in this condition?  Does `ORDER BY fr_user DESC, created DESC` change the query plan?

Answer (score 3):

(To answer @Michael, then segue into the OP's question.)  `ORDER BY fr_user DESC, created DESC` can use an index backwards *if* all are `DESC`.  Or, as in this orginal case, it can do `WHERE fr_user = constant ORDER BY created DESC` when you have `INDEX(fr_user, created)`.  It simply goes to the end of the `fr_user=1` entries in the index and walks backward.

But your question is "why are all 170 rows examined".  Well, they aren't.  The "170" is bogus because `EXPLAIN` almost always ignores `LIMIT`.  This is a known failing of `EXPLAIN`.  The Optimizer, in some situations, does take `LIMIT` into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So does that mean only 10 rows are really being examined in my case if the ratio is 100%?

Comment: Yeah, can't trust the 100%, either.

Comment: Take a look at `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`.  (If you are running a new enough version of MySQL.)